# Mouse tracking over canvas not working - PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to enable mouse tracking over a figure (plot), however the mouse tracking is only working for the area NOT INCLUDING the figure/canvas.

The minimum code to show the issue:

```
class PlotWorstRegion(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent = MatplotlibWidget):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure())
        self.canvas.axes = self.canvas.figure.add_subplot(111)

        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

        x = 0
        y = 0

        self.text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(x, y)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.text, self)

        grid.addWidget(self.label,0,0)
        grid.addWidget(self.canvas)

        self.setGeometry(10, 240, 200, 300)

        self.setWindowTitle('Event object')
        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

        self.setMouseTracking(True)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):

        x = e.x()
        y = e.y()

        text = "x: {0},  y: {1}".format(x, y)
        self.label.setText(text)
```

When I comment out `grid.addWidget(self.canvas)`, this provides tracking in the grid, except when hovering over/around the label widget. 
When I add `self.label.setMouseTracking(True)` in InitUI, the tracking is enabled for everywhere in the grid.

HOWEVER, when I uncomment  `grid.add_widget(self.canvas)` AND add `self.canvas.setMouseTracking(True)`, the tracking is 'blocked' by the canvas and the tracking is only enabled just outside the borders of the canvas.

Any help getting the mouse tracking to apply to the canvas as well would be greatly appreciated!